# How to add an animation while changing size on control

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, webforms, css-animations

What I'm trying to do is change the Panel size using CSS with transition effect.

***C#***

I tried:
`Top_frame.Style.Add("height", "0");` (with transition already added to control in css)

and: `Top_frame.Attributes.Add("style", "transition: 1s; height: 0;");`

and: `Top_frame.Attributes.Add("class", "HiddenTop_frame");` (Adding new class with prepared style)

```
.HiddenTop_frame {
    transition: 2s;
    height: 200px;
}
```

> Problem is that all ways just changed the control size without the animation.

Any ideas on how to make this size change animated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is the following. I assume the panel is already on your screen, and you would like to animate it when some postback happens.

On a postback the complete contents of your page (or an updatepanel, if you use it) is 'refreshed', and to the browser your panel is simply a new DIV, with another height.

What you could do, is manipulate the height with javascript. Then the browser applies the height change to this element, and the transition is triggered.

For example like this:

In the html markup (or via a css class) give your panel a height of 0px, and already apply a transition effect to it:

```
<asp:Panel id="Top_frame" runat="server" style="height: 0px; transition: height 1s ease 1s;"/>
```

In your eventhandler send some javascript to the browser:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "enlarge", $"<script type=text/javascript>document.getElementById('{Top_frame.ClientID}').style.height = '500px';</script>");
```

This solution only works if you aren't using UpdatePanels. If you are, you should use a ScriptManager to take care of executing script on postback.

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Top_frame, Top_frame.GetType(), "enlargefunc", "function enlarge() { document.getElementById('" + Top_frame.ClientID + "').style.height = '500px';}", true);
            }
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Top_frame, Top_frame.GetType(), "enlargeexe", $"setTimeout('enlarge()', 50);", true);
        }
```

Also, you should have a ScriptManager element somewhere on your page (probably you have).
Note that 'setTimeout' is used, so the script doesn't execute before the original height (0px) is applied when the UpdatePanel refreshes.

Although this solution works, I recommend that you take another approach: If only the contents *in* Top_frame is refreshed on postback, put the (or an) UpdatePanel inside Top_frame. In code behind you can update the contents of Top_frame. And you can call 'ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript' without the setTimeout-trick.

Comment: It works when adding the script to the PageLoad function, but when I'm trying to add the script to the button event it's not working anymore.

Comment: Are you using updatepanels?

Comment: Yes, I am. Top_frame is in it.

Comment: I edited the anwer, added a solution which can be used in combination with updatepanels

Comment: Thank you so much!